# Avahi-dnsconfd update

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am using MATE 16.04 on an ASUS X550LA with 12 GB RAM, single user, FIREFOX 59.0.1 64 bit with DuckDuckGo.

Running Ubuntu Software Updater gave me following:-

E: /var/cache/apt/archives/avahi-dnsconfd_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb: subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1

Later I used Synaptic and received the same, all applications seem to run OK, I'd appreciate an answer as to why I get this message. Also as I'm on a home network shared with a Win 10 computer, do I really need Avahi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helped for me:

```
sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo systemctl enable avahi-daemon
```

Comment: Tanks Mark that seemed to work very well.